# Can someone help me with solving a system of differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

```
Clear[s];
Eqns = {2 + Bo z[s] - Sin[\[Phi][s]]/r[s] == \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s\)]\(\[Phi][s]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s\)]\(z[s]\)\) == 
    Sin[\[Phi][s]], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(s\)]\(r[s]\)\) == Cos[\[Phi][s]], 
   z[0] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 0, r[0] == 0};
Sol = NDSolve[Eqns, {z, r, \[Phi]}, s]
```

I am having trouble solving the above equations. I tried to set a range for `s`, but it did not really work. I guess the answer is not numerical. I keep getting error message

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at s == 0.

I am not sure what this really means. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial condition `r[0] == 0` is inadmissible because it produces a singularity. Further, `Bo` must have an numerical value. The following, which corrects these faults, works.

```
With[{Bo = 1}, 
  Eqns = 
    {2 + Bo z[s] - Sin[φ[s]]/r[s] == Derivative[1][φ][s], 
     Derivative[1][z][s] == Sin[φ[s]], 
     Derivative[1][r][s] == Cos[φ[s]], 
     z[0] == 0, φ[0] == 0, r[.01] == .01}];

NDSolve[Eqns, {z, r, φ}, {s, .01, 2}]
```

[image: solution]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AlexWu. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

`r[0]==0` is making `1/r[s]` to be `1/0`. We need to avoid this by taking `r[0]==10^(-5)`. You also need to specify value for `Bo` and the domain for `s`.

```
Clear[s]; Bo = 1;

Eqns = {2 + Bo*z[s] - Sin[\[Phi][s]]/r[s] == \[Phi]'[s], 
        z'[s] == Sin[\[Phi][s]], r'[s] == Cos[\[Phi][s]], 
      z[0] == 0, \[Phi][0] == 0, r[0] == 10^(-5)};

Sol = NDSolve[Eqns, {z[s], r[s], \[Phi][s]}, {s, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!